# Aluminum coil in jockey boxes

Tags: safety

Is it safe to use aluminum coil in jockey boxes even if the tube is firstly boiled to create that protective dark layer on it?

And what is the frequency that is necessary to make and keep it with that protective dark layer?

Answer (score 2):

Aluminium was discontinued for use in casks and kegs here in the UK in the due to it slowly being dissolved by the beer when the protective epoxy liners got damaged. A layer of oxide will not protect your aluminium from being corroded by the beer, I would use stainless or plastic.

Comment: Is it some legal norm? Or just only the manufacturers that have chose to not use it? What about homebrewers?

Comment: I think it is the failure risk due to damage and the fact you can't clean Aluminium with caustic so the contamination risk is higher both biologically and from damaged liners, no-one wants a beer tasting of metal, or potentially full of Al ions, which are not great for you. I would always use stainless over aluminium, for longevity, hygine and health reasons. Not sure it was ever made illegal, but people stopped using them for the mentioned reasons. If you are in the UK and want a cask here is a good spot: https://www.brewuk.co.uk/9gal-cask.html

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't be worried about using aluminium, personally, but be VERY careful with your choice of cleaners. Most especially, don't try to use caustic. If you're at all worried, I would recommend finding a stainless coil, or using some normal beerline. Or even a cooling plate.

As a side concern, do you know where the coil has been? What has it been used for in the past, if anything?